# Angular 2 RC5 to final 2.0.0 package.json

Tags: angular

Our app is currently upgraded to RC5 and now want to move on to final 2.0.0. What are the dependencies that need to be updated in package.json?
I have included the peer-dependencies mentioned in the CHANGELOG, but npm install always fails on typings.

package.json

```
"scripts": {
"rimraf": "rimraf",
"tslint": "tslint",
"typedoc": "typedoc",
"typings": "typings",
"webpack": "webpack",
"webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
"webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
"protractor": "protractor",
"clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc typings coverage dist",
"clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
"preclean:install": "npm run clean",
"clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
"preclean:start": "npm run clean",
"clean:start": "npm start",
"watch": "npm run watch:local",
"watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
"watch:local": "npm run build:local -- --watch",
"watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
"watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
"watch:uat": "npm run uat -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
"watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
"build": "npm run build:local",
"prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
"build:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
"build:local": "webpack --config config/webpack.local.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
"build:devplus": "webpack --config config/webpack.devplus.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
"build:test": "webpack --config config/webpack.test.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached --bail",
"build:uat": "webpack --config config/webpack.uat.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached --bail",
"prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
"build:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached --bail",
"server": "npm run server:dev",
"server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --inline --progress --profile --colors --watch --display-error-details --display-cached --content-base src/",
"server:local": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.local.js --inline --progress --profile --colors --watch --display-error-details --display-cached --content-base src/",
"server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --hot",
"server:prod": "http-server dist --cors",
"webdriver:update": "npm run webdriver-manager update",
"webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
"lint": "npm run tslint 'src/**/*.ts'",
"pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
"e2e": "npm run protractor",
"e2e:live": "npm run e2e -- --elementExplorer",
"pretest": "npm run lint",
"test": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/karma/bin/karma start",
"ci": "npm run e2e && npm run test",
"docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
"start": "npm run server:local",
"start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
"postinstall": "npm run typings -- install",
"preversion": "npm test",
"version": "npm run build",
"postversion": "git push && git push --tags"
}

"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
"angular2-toaster": "0.3.6-rc.4",
"core-js": "2.4.0",
"css-loader": "0.23.1",
"fullcalendar": "^2.7.1",
"intl": "1.2.4",
"jquery": "2.2.2",
"jquery-ui": "1.10.5",
"ng2-cookies": "^0.1.5",
"ng2-file-upload": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
"node-sass": "^3.8.0",
"normalize.css": "^4.1.1",
"path-to-regexp": "^1.5.3",
"postcss": "^5.0.19",
"postcss-loader": "^0.8.2",
"primeng": "^1.0.0-beta.15",
"primeui": "^4.1.12",
"resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"sass-loader": "^3.2.3",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"tether": "^1.2.0",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
"zone.js": "0.6.21"
},
"devDependencies": {
"angular2-hmr": "~0.5.5",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "~0.17.0",
"babel-core": "^6.2.1",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple": "^6.7.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
"babel-preset-es2015-webpack": "^6.4.0",
"bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
"bootstrap-loader": "1.0.10",
"codelyzer": "0.0.15",
"compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
"css-loader": "^0.23.1",
"es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
"es6-promise-loader": "^1.0.1",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
"expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
"file-loader": "^0.8.5",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
"http-server": "^0.9.0",
"imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
"istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
"json-loader": "^0.5.4",
"karma": "^0.13.22",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
"karma-coverage": "^0.5.5",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
"karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-webpack": "1.7.0",
"lodash": "^4.6.1",
"moment": "^2.11.2",
"node-sass": "3.7.0",
"npmconf": "2.1.2",
"parse5": "^2.1.5",
"phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.2",
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
"protractor": "^3.2.2",
"raw-loader": "0.5.1",
"remap-istanbul": "^0.6.3",
"resolve-url-loader": "^1.4.3",
"rimraf": "^2.5.2",
"sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
"source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
"ts-node": "^0.7.1",
"tslint": "^3.7.1",
"tslint-loader": "^2.1.3",
"typedoc": "^0.3.12",
"typescript": "2.0.2",
"typings": "^1.0.4",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
"webpack": "^1.12.14",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
"webpack-load-plugins": "^0.1.2",
"webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
"webpack-merge": "^0.12.0",
"webpack-validator": "^1.0.0-beta.4"
}
```

What am i messing up in the package.json for npm install to fail over and over again?

tsconfig

```
`{
 "compilerOptions": {
 "target": "es5",
 "module": "commonjs",
 "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
 "experimentalDecorators": true,
 "sourceMap": true,
 "noEmitHelpers": true
 },
 "exclude": [
 "node_modules",
"typings/main.d.ts",
"typings/main"
 ],
"filesGlob": [
"./src/**/*.ts",
"./test/**/*.ts",
"!./node_modules/**/*.ts",
"src/custom_typings.d.ts",
"typings/browser.d.ts"
],
"compileOnSave": false,
"buildOnSave": false
}`
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?  Is it only failing on installing `typings`?

Comment: npm ERR! fh@1.0.4 postinstall: `npm run typings -- install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fh@1.0.4 postinstall script 'npm run typings -- install'.

Comment: what does the `scripts` section of your `package.json` look like?

Comment: Edited original question description and added the script section

Comment: Try taking the `--` out of the `npm run typings -- install`, just have `npm run typings install`

Comment: Still getting an error
npm ERR! fh@1.0.4 postinstall: `npm run typings install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fh@1.0.4 postinstall script 'npm run typings install'.

Comment: ok, try running just `typings install` from a command line (in your project directory).  If that works, maybe take the `npm run` part out (I've never had that in my scripts)

Comment: Tried `typings install`

typings ERR! message Attempted to compile "zone.js" as an external module, but it looks like a global module.

typings ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\npm\\node_modules\\typings\\dist\\bin.js" "install"
typings ERR! node -v v6.2.0
typings ERR! typings -v 1.0.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124830/discussion-between-dave-v-and-user3344978).

Comment: @DaveV  I cloned the project again, made necessary changes to the packages and ran npm install and it not error out on typings. Thank you for your help! 
But I do have some build errors now which are showing up due to the packages. Not sure what to do

Comment: I'll post an answer for this issue, if you want, open another one and we can work on the new issues in that new question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the script that was included was faulty, having a `--` between the `typings` and `install`.  Taking that out will let the typings install.  I do recommend using the newer `@types` and the `typeRoots` option if you are using Typescript 2.x

Comment: This definitely helps with the npm install ERR. However I do get build errors when the versions are 
`"typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^0.8.1",`
`ERROR in [default] C:/project/typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts:426:10
Interface 'NodeBuffer' incorrectly extends interface 'Uint8Array'.
  Types of property 'fill' are incompatible.
    Type '(value: any, offset?: number, end?: number) => Buffer' is not assignable to type '(value: number, start?: number, end?: number) => this'.
      Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type 'this'.`

Comment: What does your tsconfig look like?

Comment: Added tsconfig in the original question

Comment: try passing the `exclude` property just the typings folder instead of specifying a file: `"exclude": ["node_modules", "typings"]`, that way it doesn't try to build anything in the typings folder

Comment: also, `filesGlob` isn't a valid property any more.  It's just `files`, `include`, and/or `exclude`

Comment: I got only error only when I upgraded typescript to 2.0.2. When it was on 1.8.10 with typings: 1.0.4 , I did not receive any error

Comment: That's likely, there were a lot of changes from 1.x to 2.x

Comment: So could it be that the typings version in my package.json is not compatible with typescript 2.0.2?

Comment: I saw that you are using the `ambient` folder still, that's an even older version of typings.  I wouldn't think that the version of typings would make that much of a difference, but it could.  I would almost recommend going through and finding as many of the definitions you can from the `@types` source and using that instead of `typings`.  If you can find everything you need, it will make it a lot easier for you.

Comment: Changed the typescript back to 1.8.10 for the time being.